# How to provide Angular Website Template Open Source

Tags: angular, git, github, git-fork

I'd like to provide my Angular based website Open-Source as template. I already separated all user data and configuration into .json files in a certain directory so that users don't have to touch any code.
What is a good mechanism for providing the code, which ensures the following qualities?

1. Using the template is easy and does not require too many steps
2. When using the template, not all files of the template's repo are included (e.g. documentation of the template ect.)
3. When the template gets updated, the users that have old versions of the template in use can easily upgrade (if they don't touch the source code but only the config files there should be no conflicts)

I had the following options for this in mind:

- **GitHub template**: Could solve first two points (with help of an `on: create` workflow, see [here](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22183#discussioncomment-4585507)), but lacks the third point (because of no common git history)
- **Git fork**: Seems to have downsides compared with GitHub template in adapting the template for the first time (GitHub Repo settings not copied) but would allow more easy upgrading
- **NPM package**: Uploading my App Component as NPM package would probably allow the easiest way to update it later on. But I'm not sure how to do that exactly. As far as I understood, users would then need a own angular project and use my App Component within? I it was possible I would avoid a seperate Angular project in that case...
- **Git Submodule**: I'm not fully sure what the up-/downsides of this approach would be but it seems similar to the NPM package approach